# JQuery ajax fails to get respose from struts-2 action

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I am sending ajax request to my action class in struts-2. The data has been sent successfully but I am not getting any response from action and `jquery fail()` is running after completion instead of `done()`.

I am getting the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyProject/viewMonitor/newjsp.jsp
```

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "getCampData"
        data: {campaignId: campaignId},
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert("Camp List : " + response.campList);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
```

struts action mapping:

```
<action name="*CampData" method="{1}" class="com.monitor.CampAction">
        <result name="get">/viewMonitor/newjsp.jsp"</result>
</action>
```

My action class ***get()*** method:

```
public String get(){

    System.out.println("Camp : " + campaignId);
    String[] split = campaignId.split(", ");
    campList.addAll(Arrays.asList(split));
    System.out.println("Camp List : " + campList);
    return "get";
}
```

Comment: I think you have something wrong in the action mapping result and/or the jsp location.

Comment: jsp location is right but I don't know if it is action mapping error, want to get help.

Comment: @AnkitLamba Do you have a method `get` in the action class?

Comment: yes I have the method **get** @RomanC

Comment: And what is the method signature?

Comment: Does this method execute? What you get on the console output?

Comment: Use `<s:url>` tag for ajax url. And method with name `get`, seriously?

Comment: Use like this-<result name="get">/WEB-INF/viewMonitor/newjsp.jsp</result>    You have use unnecessary quate after .jsp. try to use full jsp path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your struts action mapping, in your result tag :

```
<result name="get">/viewMonitor/newjsp.jsp"</result>
```

you have an extra doublequote `"` at `.jsp"</result>`, I think this is the problem that your ajax is not working.